# Index Match results in #NA only on some cells

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to reference column B however I am doing a index match and on some parts it's resulting a #NA when clearly the index is there. Please advise

Current Formula: =INDEX(Winnbago_Xref!$B$2:$B$271,MATCH(A2,Winnbago_Xref!$A$2:$A$271,0))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if they trully are equal,  In an empty cell put `=A4=Winnbago_Xref!A30` where A30 is the cell in which you think there is a match.  If you get a TRUE then it should find it with the MATCH.  If FALSE then start looking for extra spaces in the data that are not visible.

Comment: Another thing to check is if you are trying to compare numbers as numbers to numbers as text.

Comment: @ScottCraner I did exactly what you mentioned and it returned false. Upon further inspection there is a leading 0 therefore #NA. Newbie mistake but I couldn't find it till now, thanks Scott

Answer (score 0):

Going off what Scott Craner advised I found there was a leading zero in the text